# I get error "uninitialized constant ContactController"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

`routes.rb` file is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root  'pages#home'
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact', via: 'get'
  match '/home',    to: 'contact#pages', via: 'get'
```

`pages_controller` is

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end

    def contact
    end

end
```

I get routing error saying "uninitialized constant ContactController". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Change your `routes.rb` file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root  'pages#home'
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact', via: :get
  match '/home',    to: 'pages#home',    via: :get
end
```

Would work!!!

In `Rails 4` with `match methods` must specify `HTTP method` otherwise would get   `RuntimeError` **"You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)"**

Answer (score 0):

`match` is deprecated. Try

```
root 'pages#home'
get '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'
get '/home', to: 'pages#home'
```

Comment: I still got "uninitialized constant ContactController" though.

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Rails 4.2.5.1

Comment: I have edited my answer. For `home` it was `contact#pages` instead of `pages#contact`.

Comment: Okay. The error disappeared but I can't go back to home page once I clicked "contact" page. seems like home.html means contact.html on local server... don't know why. any ideas?